# Memory leaks in MyFaces

Tags: jsf, memory-leaks, tomcat6, myfaces

> **EDIT: The solution that you can find in comments below assumes changing
>   JSF implemenetation from MyFaces to
>   Sun's Mojarra.**

Hi,

I have got really annoying problem with MyFaces 2.0.0 (To be more precisely I checked it out also on 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 and problem remains).

I'm writing now application under MyFaces. Briefly speaking in my application i use frameworks: Spring, Hibernate, JSF (MyFaces implementation)
My application container is Tomcat (6.0.29 version)
I use maven to build and deploy (version 3.0).

The problem is when I try to redeploy application via maven (mvn tomcat:redeploy) it tries first to undeploy application and the deploy it again. But undeploying never suceed. I've got information:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/adam] created a ThreadLocal with key of type 
[java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4b0a4d7c]) and a value of type
[org.apache.myfaces.config.RuntimeConfig] (value  org.apache.myfaces.config.RuntimeConfig@11652e61])
but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped.
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Due to this error tomcat cannot undeploy application:

```
INFO: Undeploying context [/adam]
2010-12-02 11:47:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\adam\WEB-INF\lib] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
2010-12-02 11:47:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\adam\WEB-INF] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
2010-12-02 11:47:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\adam] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
2010-12-02 11:47:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar delete
SEVERE: [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\adam] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
2010-12-02 11:47:49 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

All of my libraries in WEB-INF\lib and my file where i keep logs from Log4J cannot be deleted.

There is also connected memory leak from library that provides ELFactoryImpl:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/adam] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null]
(value [org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver$1@693985fc])
and a value of type [java.util.HashSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it
when the web application was stopped.
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

How to get rid of this memory leaks ?

I have been looking for answer really long I cannot find any solution.
I found this issue on myface's jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-2942
But I don't know what to think about it. Should I wait for version 2.0.3 ?

I think that memory leak from EL is connected to first one.

Please, help me ! ;) I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has already been reported and will be fixed. As of now you have 3 options:

1. Live with the warning message and wait until MyFaces guys release the fix.
2. Apply the proposed patch in your current MyFaces implementation.
3. Replace MyFaces by [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) (the reference implementation) which doesn't expose this problem.

Comment: "Apply the proposed patch in your current MyFaces implementation.". My question will be really stupid now ;) How to do this ? AFAIK i should use patch UNIX tool. Am I right ? But how to do this under Windows system ? By using Cygwin ?

Comment: They uses SVN. If you don't have SVN, you have to downoad a nightly build or to apply it manually on the MyFaces source and recompile/repackage the JAR. However, I can't seem to find a nightly build on the forest at http://myfaces.apache.org. The download folders are empty. Anyway, is there any reason that you prefer MyFaces over the superior Mojarra?

Comment: "Anyway, is there any reason that you prefer MyFaces over the superior Mojarra?" Only one reason: changes in documentation of my BSc Thesis and few changes in web.xml configuration. But that is not a big deal. I will try Mojarra. I hope that will help. If it will help, should I write about it in the comment ? (I am new here ;))

Comment: I've used Mojarra on Tomcat for years and I haven't ever seen those memory leaks. You can just comment here if it helped.

Comment: It didn't helped: "SEVERE: The web application [/adam] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@4d885088]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak." Later i will check with MAT what is it. Any clue ?

Comment: Hmm, I will check this later the day.

Comment: This has been introduced in the new 2.0.3 (while it works fine for 2.0.2 and before). The issue has been reported as well and is fixed for 2.1: https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1730 In the meanwhile, you might want to pick [2.0.2](https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11965&expandFolder=11965&folderID=5220) instead.

Comment: Success ! There are no memory leaks so far. But still while undeploying application tomcat is unable to remove jars from WEB-INF/lib. Sometimes all of them, sometimes jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar only. I have no clue why this happens. I will try to investigate this issue. And i have to check if mojarra doesn't changes my application behavior. Have you ever had this type of situation when tomcat could not undeploy application ?

Comment: You need to add `antiResourceLocking="true"` to the `<Context>` element in `/META-INF/context.xml`.

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks a lot ! Now I have to check if my ajax requests works fine under mojarra. But both of my problems have been solved. I own you a beer! But it can take a lot to send it to You from Poland ;) I have got a question, how do You know so much about JSF ? Years of experience or there is really got blog about JSF that I have missed ?

Comment: You're welcome. It's a combination of years of experience and a pretty strong memory. I actually own a JSF blog at http://balusc.blogspot.com. It's however mainly targeted on JSF 1.2.

Comment: I have change JSF 1.2 to 2.0 due to the fact that JSF 1.2 swallowed sometimes exceptions which were thrown by code. I have werid situation with primefaces. There is no notification in one of my page. This also happens under MyFaces 2.0.2

Comment: When using `actionListener` in JSF 1.2, it will indeed swallow exceptions. You should use `action` instead. In PrimeFaces with Ajax, you should use `p:ajaxStatus` for this. See also my answer on [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146524/javaee6-how-to-safeguard-web-application-when-the-database-shut-down).

Comment: <h:inputText id="copingFilePhaseFocus"
       rendered="#{pluginInstallerWebBean.copingFilePhaseFocus}"
       style="">
       <p:ajax ajax="true" event="focus"
        update="copingFilePhase obtainingPluginInformationPhase"
        actionListener="#{installationController.startCopyingWarFile}" />
      </h:inputText> <- This (h:inputText + p:ajax) does not work under MyFaces 2.0.2 or Mojarra 2.0.2. Do you know why ?

Comment: Is it inside a `h:form`? Does the condition of the `rendered` attribute evaluate the same during ajax request? (i.e. it's retained in next request; put bean in view scope to be sure). If you stucks, please ask a new question. Do not abuse comments for this :)