# JSF 2 : Ajax errors not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Im currently trying out the ajax feature, and im curious about how can i display the error messages occured when i do the ajax stuff ?
For example, i have a primefaces button :

```
<p:commandButton value="Refresh" update="debugPanel messages" 
   action="#{checkbocLabBean.submit}"/>
```

When testing that button, nothing seems to happen, until i check the server logs, there's an exception. It turns out that i have a typo. Should be #{checkboxLabBean.submit}.

The only thing i can think of right now is to have disable the ajax, adding ajax="false" in my case, and the error will show up.

Is there any other ways to show errors right into the browser in development phase when using ajax requests ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax requests happens asynchronously. They do by default not affect the entire document. Exceptions thrown during PrimeFaces' ajax requests are delegated to [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatusHome.jsf). You can do your thing in `<facet name="error">`.

```
<p:ajaxStatus>
    <f:facet name="start">Loading...</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="success"><h:outputText value="" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="error">An error has occurred!</f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

If you rather want to replace the current document with the error page -which is a very reasonable choice- then it's good to know that PrimeFaces uses jQuery under the covers and that you can configure jQuery as follows to do so:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        error: handleXhrError
    });

    function handleXhrError(xhr) {
        document.open();
        document.write(xhr.responseText);
        document.close();
    }
</script>
```

#### See also:

- [How to safeguard webapplication on server-side errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146524/javaee6-how-to-safeguard-web-application-when-the-database-shut-down/)
- [Handling of server-side HTTP errors in jQuery's ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738785/handling-of-server-side-http-4nn-5nn-errors-in-jquerys-ajax-requests)

Comment: I read about ajaxStatus before, but i forgot about it, haha. Very nice handling with jquery. Im not into jquery yet, but the code is very readable =) Thank you !